# Is $L_p, loc(R)$ a Banach algebra?

Tags: functional-analysis

I am not an expert in functional analysis, and I would like to know whether the space of locally integrabile functions, $L_{1,loc}(R)$ is a Banach algebra with respect to a suitable norm.

The Wikipedia entry https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_integrable_function

discusses a possible metric, but leaves my question open. I’d be happy to be forwarded to a relatively accessible reference, if available.

Comment: What muitplication do  you have in mind?

Comment: Thanks @DavidC.Ullrich. I was thinking point wise multiplication between functions, $(uv)(x) = u(x)v(x)$.

Comment: But the pointwise product of two locally integrable functions need not be locally integrable.

Comment: (When people  talk about $L^1(\Bbb R)$ as a Banach algebra the multiplication is _convolution_. But that doesn't work here either...)

Comment: I see, thank you. That answers my question, thanks

Comment: Hi David, do you know an example of a product and norm under which $L_{1,loc}(\mathbb{R})$ is a Banach Algebra?